# using functions from outside a class

Tags: c++

First of forgive me if this has been answered, i could not find it.

i m pretty new to C++ and programming in general just fumbling my way thorough. I created a class called "Angle". outside of this class i have a function to test input from user to make sure its an integer called "isInt". But i keep getting an error "identifier not fund" if i try to use the isInt function inside the Angle class. do i have no choice but to repeat the code for isInt inside the class ?

Thanks in Advance

Bellow is my code for the class and the function

```
class Angle {
private:
    int degrees;
    float minutes;
    char direction;
public:
    //Setters
    void setDegrees(int x) {
        degrees = x;
    }
    void setMinutes(float y) {
        minutes = y;
    }
    void setDirection(char z) {
        direction = z;
    }

    //Getters
    int getDegrees() {
        return degrees;
    }
    float getMinutes() {
        return minutes;
    }
    char getDirection() {
        return direction;
    }

    //Constructors
    Angle() {
        degrees = -1;
        minutes = -1;
        direction = NULL;        
    }

    //Member Functions
    void getAngleFromUser() {
        bool test = false;
        std::string temp;

        std::cout << "Please input an angle value (degrees and minutes)\n";
        while (test != true) {
            std::cout << "Please input and angle in degrees (it must be an integer): ";
            std::cin >> temp;
            test = isInt(temp);
        }
        setDegrees(std::stoi(temp));            
    }
};

bool isInt(std::string input)
{
    if (input.find_first_not_of("1234567890") != std::string::npos) {
        std::cout << "invalid input. please input integer\n";
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: _i m pretty new to C++ and programming in general just fumbling my way thorough_ Sorry, this doesn't sound like an upcoming success story. C++ is full of subtle effects and things which end up in [Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) if not done right (without any complaints of the compiler or at run-time). It's learnt at best with a good book and/or a good teacher.

Comment: If you want to read an integer as input, then read an integer directly. Don't read a string and then check if it contains any non-digit characters.

Comment: `isInt` is being used before it is declared. If that sounds confusing, pay heed to comment by @Scheff.

Comment: You defined `isInt()` after where you called it. At the point where you call it, it's just not yet known to the compiler.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the feed back, appreciate it, @Scheff, any books you recommend ?

Comment: @JaMiT, yeah, i guess i didnt do as good as job at looking for the answer before asking as i thought i did. thanks for the link.

Comment: @IvoBiz I searched for the answer instead of the question. ;) *For what it's worth, my specific search on this site was "[c++] declare function before using it is:answer".*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use any function you must declare/define it before using it.

i.e if you write
`bool isInt(std::string);` before defining your class, your problem will be solved.

**Other things**

your **getter**s (getDegrees/Minutes/Direction) should be constant.

`input` argument should be constant.

why don't you include `isInt` in your class as a private function to encapsulate it?

And what do you mean by `Null` to be assigned to a character? you may mean `\0`

`while (test != true)` **equiv** `while(!test)`

Comment: Thanks moving my prototype above the class did the trick, i m not sure sure what you mean by my getters should be constant. could you please show a quick example ?

Comment: @IvoBiz I've edited it to include what is meant by `getters`

Comment: Not a good idea to do input within member functions

Comment: @SoulimaneMammar It's not to do input. it's used to check its validity. and I suggested encapsulating it because it's used in the class. If the OP doesn't want to encapsulate it, the function pointer may be passed as an argument.